# Trouble binding data from form to action method model. List<SelectListItem> used in ViewModel

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding, selectlistitem

I'm learning ASP.Net MVC Core and i'm having some trouble understanding how to bind my form data to my action method's parameter.

My ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class RemindUsersViewModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> UsersCompleted { get; set; } 
        public List<SelectListItem> UsersNotCompleted { get; set; }
        public Course Course { get; set; }
    }
```

And my form looks like this:

```
@model List<RemindUsersViewModel>
...
@foreach (var e in Model)
{
..
<form asp-controller="ManageCourse" asp-action="RemindUsers" method="post">

    <ul>
        @for (int i = 0; i < e.UsersNotCompleted.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>
                <div>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" asp-for="@e.UsersNotCompleted[i].Selected" />
                        <span>@e.UsersNotCompleted[i].Text</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@e.UsersNotCompleted[i].Text" />
            </li>
        }
        <li>
            <button type="submit">Send reminder</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>


}
```

And in fiddler i see these values posted in the body after selecting 2/2 users and submitting:

```
e.UsersNotCompleted[2].Text =   robert@gud.se
e.UsersNotCompleted[2].Selected =   false
e.UsersNotCompleted[2].Selected =   true
e.UsersNotCompleted[1].Text =   robban@mail.se
e.UsersNotCompleted[1].Selected =   true
e.UsersNotCompleted[1].Selected =   false
e.UsersNotCompleted[0].Text =   test@test.se
e.UsersNotCompleted[0].Selected =   false
e.UsersNotCompleted[0].Selected =   true
```

How would i go ahead to bind these values in my action method correctly? Or should i redesign my ViewModel? I'm unsure if it's incorrect to have a list of my ViewModel..
Currently i'm filling these Lists of  with the users who have completed or not completed a certain course.

What i'm trying to achieve is to allow the admin to select users in a list and then make the system remind them via email to take a course. It's for a school assignment. 
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

Standard practice is to have a single ViewModel passed to the view. Not a list of ViewModels.

So, if I understand your requirements correctly, I think your view should look like:

```
@model RemindUsersViewModel
...

<form asp-controller="ManageCourse" asp-action="RemindUsers" method="post">

    <ul>
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.UsersNotCompleted.Count; i++)
        {
            <li>
                <label>
                    <input asp-for="UsersNotCompleted[i].Selected" />
                    <span>@Model.UsersNotCompleted[i].Text</span>
                </label>
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="UsersNotCompleted[i].Text" />
            </li>
        }
        <li>
            <button type="submit">Send reminder</button>
        </li>
    </ul>

</form>
```

And the controller action signature would be:

```
public IActionResult RemindUsers(RemindUsersViewModel model)
```

---

UPDATE based on your response:

you could change your ViewModel to:

```
public class RemindUsersViewModel
{
    public List<CourseModel> Courses { get; set; }        
}

public class CourseModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> UsersCompleted { get; set; } 
    public List<SelectListItem> UsersNotCompleted { get; set; }
    public Course Course { get; set; }
}
```

Then keep the original structure of your view with the double for loop. The outer loop will loop through `Courses` and the inner loop will loop through `UsersNotCompleted`.

Note you will have multiple forms on your page. When you submit an individual form, it should POST to an action signature that looks like: `public IActionResult RemindUsers(RemindUsersViewModel model)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The reason why i have a list of my ViewModel is that i've made it so each ViewModel holds a list of the users who have and have not completed the course, as well as the course data. So that way i can loop out each course with the corresponding users.

With that in mind, i would still need multiple instances of my ViewModel. Or design it differently. Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: Ah I see. I updated my answer. I hope it helps. Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks for the update, unfortunately i'm still having issues with binding the data.
I managed to bind the data by doing this really ugly workaround:

<input type="checkbox" asp-for="@Model.Courses[y].UsersNotCompleted[i].Selected" name="@("UsersNotCompleted" + "[" + i + "]" + ".Selected")"/>

But i'm not really too excited about it.. Any suggestions?
What it seems to be is that when the HTML is rendered it creates the input with a name as followed: "name="Courses[0].UsersNotCompleted[0].Selected""
I'm guessing the binding model is unable to bind because it starts with "Courses[0]

Comment: whoops, you are right. I updated my action to accept the RemindUsersViewModel instead. But even with that, it is still pretty ugly. I will try to provide you a cleaner solution in a different answer when I have time.